# How to export events for a Facebook group in the iCal format?

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups, facebook-events, icalendar

I know I can [export all of my Facebook events](http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=14490&ref_query=exp) in the iCal format, but can I export all of the events from a Facebook group I administer in the iCal format? That would allow me to have a public calendar for that group, which I can then use to create a widget on the group web site (outside of Facebook) showing the upcoming events. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about having an account that only attends the groups events and share that accounts facebook calendar events? That way when sharing you wont mix in your private life